Text on Firefox very buggy (22.04)
I'm using Firefox 123.0 on Ubuntu 22.04. Text is displayed extremely weirdly as can be seen in the screenshot below. This doesn't happen anywhere else on my OS, and doesn't occur on Google Chrome. Any ideas?


Can you try installing Firefox as a traditional deb package (instead of snap), and let us know if that fixes the issue? Sometimes, the (default)
snap package has system integration issues https://askubuntu.com/q/1399383/124466

Can whoever downvoted explain why this question was downvoted?

Have you tried to diable Hardware-Acceleration in Firefox: https://superuser.com/questions/1813088/how-to-disable-graphics-hardware-acceleration-in-firefox

Sometimes the cached font is not right.Try to reload page with Alt R Does this happen on all sites?
